# What do I have to do to use a Datalogic Magellan 800i — which has an RS-232 connection — with a USB connection?

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have a Datalogic Magellan 800i and it originally came with an RS-232 cable. What do I have to use it with a USB cable?

Comment: Get an [RS-232 to USB converter](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=Get+an+RS-232+to+USB+converter%3F&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)?

Comment: Hi GSR, indeed, or suchlike 
 https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=rs232+usb.

Comment: Just the converter will do the trick or there are drivers to be installed as well?

Answer (score 0):

Serial port to USB adapters are fairly inexpensive and common. Especially now that most modern laptops don't come with a serial port, this is a common solution. Most of them don't even require installing a driver to function either.